# How to remove one or more letter x from pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to remove the words containing only letter x from pandas series but it is not working as expected.
How to remove words like `x xx xxx  xxxx` which can have any number of x only from the pandas series?

## My attempt

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',500)

data = np.array(['transworld system inc trying colect xx xxxx debt mine owed inacurate',
       'complaint cals ocur betwen xx xx xx xx cel job ',
       'company violated',
       'previously xxxx xxxx xxxx requested experian actualy mine xxxx xxxx instead',
       'company xx trans union xx noticed '])
                
                
s = pd.Series(data)
s.str.replace(r'(\sx+\s)',r' ',regex=True)
```

## Output

I was expecting space letter*N space replaced by one space, but it is not working.
How the problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\b` for word boundary, so `'xxx abcd'` can get replaced. Since the `x` and   can be interleaved and you would remove them all, you can just use:

```
s.str.replace(r'\b[x\s]+\b',' ')
```

Output:

```
0    transworld system inc trying colect debt mine ...
1                  complaint cals ocur betwen cel job 
2                                     company violated
3    previously requested experian actualy mine ins...
4                         company trans union noticed 
dtype: object
```